# Another way to say "do as you please"?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

I remember that there was a way to say "do as you please" and it was something like "do as you thou".

The last word was something like tho/though. I just remember that it started with "th". Can anyone suggest a phrase that might fit this?

Comment: Do as it pleases thee...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are remembering

> Do what thou wilt shall be the whole of the Law

[LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thelema) attributed to Aleister Crowley

Answer (score 0):

There's "Do as you feel", which starts with an "f" rather than a "th". But then I tend to pronounce them the same anyway. It gets [3.8m hits on google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=3cafWsnJMIrVgQaj9xg&q=%22do%20as%20you%20feel%22&oq=%22do%20as%20you%20feel%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1j0i8i30k1l7.2674.4106.0.5832.2.2.0.0.0.0.68.114.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.114...0i22i30k1.0.itK0MmmPgCo).

Alternatively, slightly different is "Do whatever you feel". [1.6m hits on google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=5MafWsXrM6HdgAajxIEY&q=%22do%20whatever%20you%20feel%22&oq=%22do%20whatever%20you%20feel%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l3j0l3j0i30k1l4.162247.163470.0.165103.8.8.0.0.0.0.80.506.8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.506...0i13k1j0i67k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.Hr9IscZqxWw), many of which are actually "Do whatever you feel *like*". Though of course it was used without the "like" in the [Village People hit Y.M.C.A](https://genius.com/Village-people-ymca-lyrics). Probably because it rhymed with "have a good meal".